# Save a picture of a signature to a file in Rhodes on Android

Tags: android, image, storage, rhodes

I am trying to implement signature capture using Rhodes targeting an Android tab. I have managed to get the canvas and scribble on it. But am unable to save the signature at a desired location. The `signature_uri` takes the default location as `db/db-files/Image-XXXXXX.png`.

This was the code in the sample example:

```rb
def signature_callback
if @params['status'] == 'ok'
  #create signature record in the DB
  signature = SignatureUtil.new({'signature_uri'=>@params['signature_uri']})
  signature.save
  puts "new Signature object: " + signature.inspect
end
```

**In the console I got**:

```
APP| RHO serve: /app/Settings/signature_callback
I/APP     (  801): I 01/26/2012 11:36:20:236 0000032e                  APP| Params: {"status"=>"ok", "signature_uri"=>"db/db-files/Image_20120126113618375.png", "rho_callback"=>"1"}
I/APP     (  801): I 01/26/2012 11:36:20:238 0000032e                  APP| *******************ok****************
I/APP     (  801): I 01/26/2012 11:36:20:238 0000032e                  APP| %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%db/db-files/Image_20120126113618375.png%%%%%%%%%%%
I/APP     (  801): I 01/26/2012 11:36:20:239 0000032e                  APP| App error: can't convert Symbol into Integer
I/APP     (  801):  lib/rhom/rhom_object_factory.rb:67:in `[]'
I/APP     (  801): lib/rhom/rhom_object_factory.rb:67:in `initialize'
I/APP     (  801): apps/app/Settings/controller.rb:34:in `new'
I/APP     (  801): apps/app/Settings/controller.rb:34:in `signature_callback'
I/APP     (  801): lib/rho/rhocontroller.rb:91:in `serve'
I/APP     (  801): lib/rho/rhoapplication.rb:209:in `serve'
I/APP     (  801): lib/rho/rho.rb:822:in `serve'
I/APP     (  801): E 01/26/2012 11:36:20:248 00000321                  Net| Request failed. HTTP Code: 500 returned. HTTP Response:         <html>
I/APP     (  801):             <head>
I/APP     (  801):                 <meta name="viewport" content="width=320"/>
I/APP     (  801):             </head>
I/APP     (  801):             <body>
I/APP     (  801):                 <h2>Server Error</h2>
I/APP     (  801):                 <p>
I/APP     (  801): Error: can't convert Symbol into Integer<br/>Trace: <br/
```

Now instead of this database storage, I want to save it in a desired location. Please share your views.

Comment: Can you show us the trace please? the others : please read the question. He has already captured the signature, but he wants to save it with Rhodes. This is the real problem, it's not "How to capture a signature on Android".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you checked out this page: http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/device-caps#file-system-access ? It looks to me like you need to save the image to the DB and use the Rho::RhoApplication::get_blob_path(image.image_uri) method to open the file. Then you should be able to use the file system API to create a new file and write the contents of the image to it wherever you choose.

Comment: This was pretty close to What we did in our project. Basically the signature_uri returns the location of the saved image(which I somehow just could not access). We pushed this location as the source of image to a web service and created a record in the DB. Verified the image being saved by the size of the file being stored. Number of strokes proportional to size of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to pass sd card location in signature uri.
Please note to give permission of read write for sd card in manifest.

Else

Copy the signature file to desire location from internal package but this is duplicacy of work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Manish and apologies for the late reply. Tried that but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The bellow code may useful to you

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Images;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

 public class CaptureSignature extends Activity {

LinearLayout mContent;
signature mSignature;
Button mClear, mGetSign, mCancel;
public static String tempDir;
public int count = 1;
public String current = null;
private Bitmap mBitmap;
View mView;
File mypath;

private String uniqueId;
private EditText yourName;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.signature);

    tempDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + getResources().getString(R.string.external_dir) + "/";
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    File directory = cw.getDir(getResources().getString(R.string.external_dir), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    prepareDirectory();
    uniqueId = getTodaysDate() + "_" + getCurrentTime() + "_" + Math.random();
    current = uniqueId + ".png";
    mypath= new File(directory,current);


    mContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    mSignature = new signature(this, null);
    mSignature.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    mContent.addView(mSignature, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    mClear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clear);
    mGetSign = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getsign);
    mGetSign.setEnabled(false);
    mCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    mView = mContent;

    yourName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourName);

    mClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {       
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Cleared");
            mSignature.clear();
            mGetSign.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });

    mGetSign.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {       
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Saved");
            boolean error = captureSignature();
            if(!error){
                mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                mSignature.save(mView);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("status", "done");
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtras(b);
                setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);  
                finish();
            }
        }
    });

    mCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {       
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Canceled");
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("status", "cancel");
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtras(b);
            setResult(RESULT_OK,intent); 
            finish();
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.w("GetSignature", "onDestory");
    super.onDestroy();
}

private boolean captureSignature() {

    boolean error = false;
    String errorMessage = "";


    if(yourName.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
        errorMessage = errorMessage + "Please enter your Name\n";
        error = true;
    }  

    if(error){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 105, 50);
        toast.show();
    }

    return error;
}

private String getTodaysDate() {

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int todaysDate =     (c.get(Calendar.YEAR) * 10000) +
    ((c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) * 100) +
    (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    Log.w("DATE:",String.valueOf(todaysDate));
    return(String.valueOf(todaysDate));

}

private String getCurrentTime() {

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int currentTime =     (c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * 10000) +
    (c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) * 100) +
    (c.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    Log.w("TIME:",String.valueOf(currentTime));
    return(String.valueOf(currentTime));

}


private boolean prepareDirectory()
{
    try
    {
        if (makedirs())
        {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Could not initiate File System.. Is Sdcard mounted properly?", 1000).show();
        return false;
    }
}

private boolean makedirs()
{
    File tempdir = new File(tempDir);
    if (!tempdir.exists())
        tempdir.mkdirs();

    if (tempdir.isDirectory())
    {
        File[] files = tempdir.listFiles();
        for (File file : files)
        {
            if (!file.delete())
            {
                System.out.println("Failed to delete " + file);
            }
        }
    }
    return (tempdir.isDirectory());
}

public class signature extends View
{
    private static final float STROKE_WIDTH = 5f;
    private static final float HALF_STROKE_WIDTH = STROKE_WIDTH / 2;
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Path path = new Path();

    private float lastTouchX;
    private float lastTouchY;
    private final RectF dirtyRect = new RectF();

    public signature(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
    }

    public void save(View v)
    {
        Log.v("log_tag", "Width: " + v.getWidth());
        Log.v("log_tag", "Height: " + v.getHeight());
        if(mBitmap == null)
        {
            mBitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap (mContent.getWidth(), mContent.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);;
        }
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream mFileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

            v.draw(canvas);
            mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, mFileOutStream);
            mFileOutStream.flush();
            mFileOutStream.close();
            String url = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), mBitmap, "title", null);
            Log.v("log_tag","url: " + url);
            //In case you want to delete the file
            //boolean deleted = mypath.delete();
            //Log.v("log_tag","deleted: " + mypath.toString() + deleted);
            //If you want to convert the image to string use base64 converter

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.v("log_tag", e.toString());
        }
    }

    public void clear()
    {
        path.reset();
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();
        mGetSign.setEnabled(true);

        switch (event.getAction())
        {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
            lastTouchX = eventX;
            lastTouchY = eventY;
            return true;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            resetDirtyRect(eventX, eventY);
            int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
            for (int i = 0; i < historySize; i++)
            {
                float historicalX = event.getHistoricalX(i);
                float historicalY = event.getHistoricalY(i);
                expandDirtyRect(historicalX, historicalY);
                path.lineTo(historicalX, historicalY);
            }
            path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
            break;

        default:
            debug("Ignored touch event: " + event.toString());
            return false;
        }

        invalidate((int) (dirtyRect.left - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                (int) (dirtyRect.top - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                (int) (dirtyRect.right + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                (int) (dirtyRect.bottom + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH));

        lastTouchX = eventX;
        lastTouchY = eventY;

        return true;
    }

    private void debug(String string){
    }

    private void expandDirtyRect(float historicalX, float historicalY)
    {
        if (historicalX < dirtyRect.left)
        {
            dirtyRect.left = historicalX;
        }
        else if (historicalX > dirtyRect.right)
        {
            dirtyRect.right = historicalX;
        }

        if (historicalY < dirtyRect.top)
        {
            dirtyRect.top = historicalY;
        }
        else if (historicalY > dirtyRect.bottom)
        {
            dirtyRect.bottom = historicalY;
        }
    }

    private void resetDirtyRect(float eventX, float eventY)
    {
        dirtyRect.left = Math.min(lastTouchX, eventX);
        dirtyRect.right = Math.max(lastTouchX, eventX);
        dirtyRect.top = Math.min(lastTouchY, eventY);
        dirtyRect.bottom = Math.max(lastTouchY, eventY);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Wasn't looking for an activity class/android code fragment buddy. Thanks anyways